# Nesting Schema.org 'Person' in 'Article', using Microdata

Tags: html, microdata, schema.org, google-rich-snippets-tool

On a press page I'm using Schema.org’s `Article`. I tried to add a `Person` nested within `Article`, but it did not validate in Google’s Testing Tool.

```html
<ul class="thumbnails" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" additionaltype="http://schea.org/Person">
    <li class="row-fluid">
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><div class="sprite"></div></a>
        <div class="span10">
            <h3 itemprop="headline"><span itemprop="name">The Person</span> teams up with <span itemprop="affiliation">THE Company</span> to support <span itemprop="worksFor">The Cause</span></h3>
            <p itemprop="description">Lorem ipsum<span itemprop="jobTitle">floral designer</span> and <span itemprop="jobTitle">model</span> and <span itemprop="jobTitle">mom</span> more text</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are attempting to claim that an Article is also a Person, which doesn't make sense semantically. If you are trying to claim that Person is an author of Article, there is an 'author' property of Article to do this. The `additonaltype` property is only useful when you are dealing with 'nested' types -- in other words, the properties you specify are common to both items. Obviously, an article and a person don't have many properties in common.

Secondly, `additionaltype` is a property, so you should specify it as follows:

```
<ul class="thumbnails" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
<meta itemprop="additionaltype" content="http://schema.org/Person">
```

That said, I'm not sure whether any search engines support this property, so I wouldn't necessarily recommend its use. If there are properties you don't want explicitly printed, you can still repeat them in meta tags for each item you are using.

Comment: It's not possible to specify something which is not related to the outer schema type but within the content of?

Comment: Note that the `link` element (instead of the `meta`) element [must be used](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669) if the value is a URI (like it’s the case for the `additionaltype` property).